# event handler not working properly in loop

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to apply some classes to html elements via foor loop. The problem is that the loop variable doesn't work correctly.

```js
'use strict'

  window.onload = function(){
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("div")

    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
      elements[i].addEventListener("click", a(this, i), false)
    }

    function a(e, x){
      if(!e.className){
        e.className = "class".concat(x)
      }
      else {
        e.classList.remove(e.className)
      }
    }
  }
```

```css
  div{
    background-color: red;
  }

  .class0{
    background-color: blue;
  }

  .class1{
    background-color: purple;
  }
```

Comment: you have `a(this, i)`, `this` is the `window` global object not an element

Comment: do i remove it and just put 'i'?

Comment: I think you meant to do something like `a.bind(elements[i],i)`

Comment: i want to add classes to the elements by using the loop variable in a function, the bind method gave me this error "Cannot create property 'className' on number '1'"

Comment: If you do just `.addEventListener("click", a, false)` and use `this` inside the function, and stop adding the index to the classes, and add a common string instead, it gets a lot easier. Also, strings don't concat.

Comment: you can get the target using `e.target`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/u2fooyxc/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Patrick suggested do this:

```
  window.onload = function(){
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("div")

    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
      elements[i].addEventListener("click", a.bind(window, elements[i],i), false)
    }

    function a(e, x){
      if(!e.className){
        e.className = "class".concat(x)
      }
      else {
        e.classList.remove(e.className)
      }
    }
  }
```

You were invoking the function a and assigning its result as an event handler.

With bind you create a function that will invoke `a` passing as arguments the element and the index.